# Генератор случайных слов без повторяющихся букв без поиска

Tags: алгоритм, олимпиада, комбинаторика, генерация-случайных-данных

Какие параметры передаются генератору:

- x - номер слова;
- N - размер алфавита;
- L - длина выходного слова.

Необходимо реализовать нерекурсивный алгоритм, который по переданным трём параметрам будет возвращать слово.

Алфавит - латинские буквы в алфавитном порядке, капсом.

Для `N=5`, `L=3` построим соответствие `x` словам:

- 0: ABC
- 1: ABD
- 2: ABE
- 3: ACB
- 4: ACD
- 5: ACE
- 6: ADB
- 7: ADC
- 8: ADE
- 9: AEB
- 10: AEC
- 11: AED
- 12: BAC
- ...

Моя реализация алгоритма работает на L=1; 2. Но на L=3 появляются ошибки. Сам алгоритм построен на сдвигах при обращении к алфавиту. Массив h хранит индексы букв в новом словаре (из которого исключены символы, которые уже попали в слово). Массив A хранит приведения индексов h в исходный словарь (добавляет отступы за каждый удалённый из алфавита символ слева). Таким образом, в конечном итоге, массив `A` хранит размещения без повторений.

```
private static String getS(int x, int N, int L) {
    String s = "ABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQ";
    String out = "";

    int[] h = new int[N];
    int[] A = new int[N];

    for (int i = 0; i < L; i++) {
        h[i] = (x / (factory(N - 1 - i)/factory(N - L))) % (N-i);

        int sum = h[i];

        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) 
            sum += ((h[i] >= h[j])?1:0);
        
        A[i] = sum;
        out += s.charAt(A[i]);

    }

    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Существует `F=A(N, L) = N!/(N-L)!` нужных **[размещений](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)**.

Так что можно сгенерировать случайное число в диапазоне `0..F-1` и построить размещение, соответствующее этому номеру.

А чтобы получить размещение по номеру (в лексикографическом порядке), можно использовать следующее - первый элемент множества стоит на первом месте в `A(n-1,l-1)` размещений (в примере из вопроса это 12 штук, начинающихся с `A`). Затем исключаем использованный элемент из списка, и аналогично находим элемент на второй позиции и т.д.

Вот пример на Delphi из [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47103321/distinct-permutation-subset-rank-and-unrank-in-delphi/47106973#47106973) (`div` - целочисленное деление, `mod`, остаток от деления, `%`)

Для аргументов `5, 3, 15` (номер 15) получается размещение `1,2,0`, соответствующее `BCA`

```
function ArrangementByRank(n, k, rank: Integer): string;

    function NumArrNK(n, k: Integer): Int64;
    var
      i: Integer;
    begin
      Result := 1;
      for i := 0 to k - 1 do
        Result := Result * (n - i);
    end;

  var
    Dig: array of Byte;
    i, j, id, ank: Integer;
  begin
    Result := '';
    SetLength(Dig, n);
    for i := 0 to n - 1 do
       Dig[i] := i;  //initial digit list

    for i := 1 to k do begin
      ank := NumArrNK(n - i, k - i);  //might be optimized
      id := rank div ank;
      rank := rank mod ank;   //prepare for the next round
      Result := Result + IntToStr(Dig[id]);
      for j := id to n - i - 1 do
        Dig[j] := Dig[j + 1];  //squeeze digit list
    end;
  end;
```

Перевод на Java: ([тест на IdeOne](https://ideone.com/c4otWU))

```
public static int NumArrNK(int n, int k) {
    int out = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i <= k - 1; i++)
        out *= n - i;

    return out;
}

public static String ArrByR(int n, int k, int x){
    String s = "ABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQ";
    int[] Dig = new int[n];

    int id, ank;

    String out = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        Dig[i] = i;

    for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++) {

        ank = NumArrNK(n - i, k - i);  //might be optimized
        id = x / ank;
        x = x % ank;   //prepare for the next round
        out = out + s.charAt(Dig[id]);

        for (int j = id; j < n - i; j++)
            Dig[j] = Dig[j + 1];

    }

    return out;
}
```

Comment: а в чём суть функции NumArrNK? Переписав решение на Java у меня получилось 33 неверных значения против 6 ошибок в моём решении...

Comment: Это вычисление функции A(n,k). Вы проверили решение на простом примере?

Comment: проверил на всех значениях от 0 до 59. Похоже что оно возвращает размещения с повторениями

Comment: [Вот проверка на ideone](https://ideone.com/lti1ei), повторений нет. Можете показать переведённый код хоть на той же ideone?

Comment: ваш код написан с учётом особенностей синтаксиса Паскаля, который я не могу как понять, так и интерпретировать в понятные мне ЯП... https://ideone.com/UwopDh

Comment: Перевели вы нормально, только упустили  for (int j = **id**; j < n - i; j++)            Dig[j] = Dig[j + 1];  https://ideone.com/c4otWU

Comment: в таком случае способ действительно работает! Остался один момент: всё же считаю правильным функцию NumArrNK расписать как частное факториалов, если я верно понял её суть. В целом, пожалуй, с этой задачей я справлюсь. Ведь функция имеет примерно такой смысл?

Comment: Да, можно, но неэффективно - если считать, как частное факториалов - то вычислений ненужных больше, и промежуточные числа будут велики. Ведь в частном факториалов сокращаются многие множители